# C++ build error: class does not name a type

Tags: c++, class, build, compiler-errors, include

I rearranged some code, and now I get following error:

```
g++ main.cpp myframe.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags --libs std` -o main
myframe.cpp:5:1: error: ‘Myframe’ does not name a type
```

I'm pretty sure the error is related to inclusions, not to wrong code

Here are the source files (relevant parts only):

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "myframe.h"

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit(){  
    Myframe *menu = new Myframe(wxT("Application"));
    menu->Show(true);
    return true;
};
```

main.h:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
  public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
```

myframe.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"

Myframe::Myframe(const wxString& title) 
/// ^ ERROR
       : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(300, 300))
{
  ...
}
```

myframe.h:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/menu.h>

class Myframe : public wxFrame
{
public:
    Myframe(const wxString& title);

    ...
};

...(function definitions,event table and enums)
```

Comment: You need `#include "myframe.h"` in `myframe.cpp`.

Comment: @songyuanyao. This would result in multiple definition of Myframe, because it was already included in main.cpp ...

Comment: You shouldn't put function definitions in `myframe.h`, move them all to `myframe.cpp`. Declarations for header file, definitions for implementation file.

Comment: @westernCiv Use include guards. Just look up *any* example of headers and implementation files.

Comment: @westernCiv: Writing a GUI application with a 3rd-party framework is not exactly the best way to start learning C++. Include guards in headers are a very basic concept of the language and must be fully understood before approaching such complex topics.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `#include <myframe.h>` into "myframe.cpp" file.
because there is not definition of Myframe in "myframe.cpp" file.